# How to matching an exact word in C using File handling and strstr?

Tags: c, file-handling, strstr

I have this code where I find a specific word in a file and count how many times it was repeated, but it seems that it also counts the similar words.

Example:

I'm searching the word `the`, but it also counts `they`, `them`, `there`, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
FILE *fpointer;
char buscar[100];
char palabra[50];
char temp[512];
char *pos;

int wCount = 0;
int i;


printf("Ingresar archivo a buscar:\n");
scanf("%s", buscar);

printf("Ingresar palabra a buscar:\n");
scanf("%s", palabra);


fpointer = fopen(buscar, "r");

if (fpointer == NULL)
{
    perror("Error al buscar el archivo\n");
}else{
    //Obtenemos el string en la variable temporal
    while((fgets(temp,512,fpointer)) != NULL){
        i = 0;
        //Usamos strstr para buscar si la palabra existe en el texto 
        while ((pos = strstr(temp + i, palabra)) != NULL){
            i = (pos - temp) + 1;
            wCount++;
        }
    }
}

printf("La palabra '%s' fue encontrado %d veces", palabra, wCount);
fclose(fpointer);

return 0;
}
```

So my question is how can I make it so it only counts the word `the`?

Comment: Did you consider search for " the ", " the.", " the," etc.? Or to otherwsie only count if there are non-letters around?

Comment: Please provide sample inputs which work and which do not work, together with their resutls and in comparison with what would be the desired results.

Comment: OT: `printf("La palabra '%s' fue encontrado %d veces", palabra, wCount); fclose(fpointer);` should be within the `else` block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for the search term "as a whole word".
To do so either search for the expected allowed characters around it, e.g. " the ",
or search for the word as you do and then check that there are non-letters around it before counting the find.  I.e. look one letter back and one letter ahead, if they are present, and check that they are not "word letters" (which depends on your language).
This is not trivial, but the concept should be clear.

Comment: Right. One more issue is when words falls in the boundary of read (i.e. at 512).

Comment: @gobinda True, but that would be about false negative counting, while this question I perceive as being about false positive counting. However, for a full solution of the problem including foreseeable problems,  that is something to keep in mind. If you make a well explained answer (as addition to mine) I would upvote yours.

Answer (score 1):

`strstr` function find a sub-string in the file. It does not know anything about words.
When found a location where the word appears, you need to make sure it is actually only this word.
I can think of a few ways:

- when found, check that there is a white space around the word before and after it. you can use `isspace()` to do that. Make sure you do not check negative indices or after the end of the string
- Use a regular expression to find a word match
- Using fscanf. something like `fscanf(f, " %1023s", x)`.

Comment: Whitespace is not enough, think of punctuation (though unlikely in the special case of "the"). Regular expressions is not a feature of `strstr()`, which OP asks about. Your fscanf approach is interesting, would you like to explain more about that?

Answer (score 0):

A small illustration which uses your example for searching for "the". As the other answers have already indicated, you can decide what is and is not acceptable for a character after an occurrence of 'the'. In your existing code you can just add `isalpha` and `isdigit` to check for alphabets or digits and advance 'i' accordingly. The sample program below returns 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{
    char test_str[] = "there is the test string 'the'";
    char key[] = "the";
    char *pos = NULL;
    int wCount = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (test_str[i] && ((pos = strstr (test_str + i, key)) != NULL)) {
        if ((isalpha(pos[strlen(key)])) || (isdigit(pos[strlen(key)]))) {
            i = (pos - test_str) + 1;
        } else {
            i = (pos - test_str) + strlen (key);
            wCount++;
        } 
    }

    printf("\nTotal matches: %d\n", wCount);
    return 0;
}
```